# using Three.js in Nextjs 14 - ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, next.js, three.js

I know this specific error has been asked here multiple times but i think this situation is unique enough to deserve its own post.

So i Just started thinkering with three.js in nextjs 14.
Everything seems to work perfectly locally but i still see the following error:
**ReferenceError: document is not defined**

I think there's a point in here somewhere that uses the document to early to create the canvas i think but i haven't located it yet as i suppose it will be in the threejs code itself.

Anyone here done something similar like this and knows where this issue get triggered?

```js
    "use client";
    export const dynamic = "auto";
    import { ISSPosition, fetchISSPosition } from "@/lib/api";
    import { convertCoordsToSphere } from "@/lib/functions";
    import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import * as THREE from "three";

    const earthRadius = 10;
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Fog setup
    ...

    // Camera and renderer setup
    ...

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      alpha: true,
      antialias: true,
    });

    // Lighting setup
    ...

    // Earth model setup
    const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(earthRadius, 64, 64);
    const earthMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      shininess: 350,
      map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("/earth_texture.jpg"),
      bumpMap: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("/earth_texture.jpg"),
    });
    const earth = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, earthMat);
    earth.receiveShadow = true;
    earth.rotation.x = 0.3;
    scene.add(earth); // Add Earth to the scene upfront

    // ISS model setup
    ...

    const animate = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      earth.rotation.y -= 0.001;

      renderer?.render(scene, camera);
    };

    const ThreeScene = () => {
      const [issPosition, setIssPosition] = useState<ISSPosition>();
      const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchISSData = async () => {
          setIssPosition(await fetchISSPosition());
        };

        const intervalId = setInterval(fetchISSData, 5000);

        if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
          containerRef.current?.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        }

        animate();

        const handleResize = () => {
          if (renderer) {
            let size =
              window.innerWidth * 0.8 > 800 ? 800 : window.innerWidth * 0.8;
            renderer.setSize(size, size);
          }
        };

        handleResize();
        window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

        return () => {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
        };
      }, []);

      useEffect(() => {
        const animate = () => {
          requestAnimationFrame(animate);

          if (issPosition) {
            const pointCoords = convertCoordsToSphere(
              Number(issPosition.iss_position.latitude),
              -Number(issPosition.iss_position.longitude),
              earthRadius
            );

            issPoint.position.copy(pointCoords.applyMatrix4(earth.matrix));
            scene.add(issPoint);
          }

          renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        animate();
      }, [issPosition]);

      return (
        typeof window !== "undefined" && (
          <>
            <div className="m-auto max-w-fit" ref={containerRef}></div>
            {issPosition ? (
              <div className="flex flex-col gap-2 mb-8 w-fit justify-center items-center mx-auto">
                <span>Latitude: {issPosition?.iss_position.latitude}</span>
                <span>Longitude: {issPosition?.iss_position.longitude}</span>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div className="flex gap-4 justify-center">
                <p className="mb-4">Locating ISS</p>
                <i className="border-b- border-primary w-4 h-4 rounded-full animate-spin"></i>
              </div>
            )}
          </>
        )
      );
    };

    export default ThreeScene;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this issue is,

Next js performs server side rendering by default. This means your JavaScript code get executed on the server before it gets sent to the client's browser. Since the `document` object is a part of Browser API and does not exist on the server, you encounter this error when your code tries to access it during SSR.

Even thought it's seems fine in local environment, because you execute `npm run dev`, the app will not run in production. Try running `npm build`, then it'll show this error and want complete the build. So to build, you need to resolve the issue.

The `document` error you're encountering likely stems from the initialization of your Three.js scene, especially the renderer, as the `THREE.WebGLRenderer()` uses the `document` to create a `<canvas>` element. Since this occurs outside of any client-side checks or lifecycle methods, it's evaluated in the server-side context where `document` is undefined.

To fix this, you should ensure that any code using `document` or other browser-specific APIs is executed only on the client side. In Next.js, this is typically handled by guarding such code with checks like `if (typeof window !== "undefined") { ... }` which you've already done for part of your code.

But, the renderer is created outside of any component lifecycle method or client-side check, leading to the SSR issue.

I have modified your code,

```js
const ThreeScene = () => {
  const [issPosition, setIssPosition] = useState<ISSPosition>();
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [renderer, setRenderer] = useState<THREE.WebGLRenderer | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Ensure this runs only on the client side
    if (typeof window !== "undefined" && !renderer) {
      const newRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        alpha: true,
        antialias: true,
      });
      setRenderer(newRenderer);
      containerRef.current?.appendChild(newRenderer.domElement);
    }
  }, [renderer]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchISSData = async () => {
      setIssPosition(await fetchISSPosition());
    };

    const intervalId = setInterval(fetchISSData, 5000);

    // Move the animation code inside this useEffect
    if (renderer && typeof window !== "undefined") {
      const animate = () => {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        earth.rotation.y -= 0.001;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      };

      animate();

      const handleResize = () => {
        let size = window.innerWidth * 0.8 > 800 ? 800 : window.innerWidth * 0.8;
        renderer.setSize(size, size);
      };

      handleResize();
      window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    }

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, [renderer, issPosition]); // Added renderer to dependency array

  // The rest of your component...
};
```

Comment: Seems like that's correct, i also noticed that it seems like there are other function from three.js as well. Once i moved them all it seemed to work, thanks for the info!